# UIScrollView keyboard dismiss on drag doesn't call resignFirstResponder on UIView with custom inputView keyboard on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, inputview

I have a `UIView` which draws a signature. The signature is inputed via a custom inputView on the signature view. 
When drawing the signature view, I use the fact that it's the first responder to highlight the view as being edited, and I also override the `resignFirstResponder` method to work out when to stop showing it as being edited.

So the code looks something like this:

```
@implementation SignatureView 

-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL result = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    [self showEditingMode];
    return result;
}

-(BOOL) resignFirstResponder {
    BOOL result = [super resignFirstResponder];
    [self showViewingMode];
    return result;
}

-(UIView *) inputView {
    if (!keyboard)
      keyboard = [[SignatureKeyboardView alloc] initWithStuff:stuff....];
    return keyboard;
}

@end
```

The problem I'm having is that on iOS 11, the `resignFirstResponder` method is no longer getting called. On previous versions of iOS, it used to get called and I could then change the UI to show that it's no longer being edited.

This ONLY HAPPENS when the `UIScrollView` is set to dismiss the keyboard when dragged, and the user drags the `UIScrollView`.
If the user instead taps another `UIView` that can become a first responder e.g. a `UITextField`, then `resignFirstResponder` gets called.

Am I missing something that changed in iOS11 or have I hit a bug?

Comment: @molf where you able to resolve this issue

Comment: Hey @salabaha - no I never was able to work it out. I ended up working around it by listening to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification and then doing what I need to do. Not ideal but it works.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did made the same workaround by subscribing to Keyboard notifications and it worked for.